# Is there a short proof that the Kostka number $K_{\lambda \mu}$ is non-zero whenever $\lambda$ dominates $\mu$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

This is maybe a little basic for MathOverflow, but I'm hoping it will get some interesting answers.

Let $\unrhd$ be the dominance order on partitions of $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
For partitions $\lambda$ and $\mu$ of $n$, the *Kostka Number* $K_{\lambda\mu}$ is the number of semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and content $\mu$.

If $t$ is such a tableau then the $\mu_1+\cdots +\mu_r$ entries $k$ of $t$ such that $k \le r$ all lie in the first $r$ rows of $t$. Hence $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_r \ge \mu_1 + \cdots + \mu_r$ for each $r$ and so $\lambda \unrhd \mu$.

> Is there a short combinatorial proof of the converse: if $\lambda \unrhd \mu$ then $K_{\lambda\mu} > 0$?

A constructive proof, maybe using the characterization of neighbours in the dominance order by single box moves on Young diagrams, would be especially welcome.

**Edit.** Using some representation theory it's possible to make this strategy work. The following is the symmetric functions version of Theorem 2.2.20 in the textbook by James and Kerber. Obviously $K_{\lambda\lambda} = 1$. Let $\mu$ and $\mu^\star$ be neighbours 
in the dominance order, with $\mu \rhd \mu^\star$, so $\mu^\star_i=\mu_i-1$, $\mu^\star_j = \mu_j+1$ for some $i < j$, and $\mu^\star_k = \mu_k$ if $k\not=i,j$. Since $h_{(a,b)} = h_{(a+1,b-1)} + s_{(a,b)}$ whenever $a \ge b$, we have

$$h_{\mu^\star} = \bigl(\prod_{k\not=i,j} h_{\mu_k} \bigr) h_{\mu_i-1}h_{\mu_j+1}=
\bigl(\prod_{k\not=i,j}h_{\mu_k}\bigr) \bigl( h_{\mu_i}h_{\mu_j} + s_{(\mu_i-1,\mu_j+1)} \bigr) $$

and so if $f = \prod_{k\not=i,j}h_{\mu_k}$ then

$$K_{\lambda\mu^\star} = \langle s_\lambda, h_{\mu^\star} \rangle = \langle s_\lambda, h_\mu \rangle + \langle s_\lambda, f s_{(\mu_i-1,\mu_j+1)} \rangle = K_{\lambda\mu} + \langle s_\lambda, f s_{(\mu_i-1,\mu_j+1)} \rangle \ge K_{\lambda\mu}.$$

Comment: Does not the most primitive filling of the diagram obviously work? I mean, fill all rows in succession using first $\mu_1$ ones, then $\mu_2$ twos, etc. Then the $r$th row will start with at most $\mu_1+...+\mu_r-\lambda_1-...-\lambda_{r-1}$ $r$s followed by larger numbers, and strict increase in the columns will be guaranteed: if say $s$ is written at the same position $p$ in the $r$th and the $r+1$st row, then $s$ occupies all positions starting from $p$ in the $r$th row and all positions up to $p$ in the $r+1$st row, which would imply $\mu_s>\lambda_r$ for $s>r$, contradicting domination.

Comment: This does not work for $\lambda=(4,1,1)$ and $\mu=(2,2,2)$.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, you also cannot fill in the shape by columns, at each step inserting the smallest number possible. E.g., $\lambda=(3,3)$, $\mu=(2,2,2)$.

Comment: Is there a simple proof of this fact using representation theory?

Comment: @RichardStanley Thank you! It took me a while to figure out what was my mistake: it is at the end, $\mu_s>\lambda_r$ for $s>r$ does not contradict dominance.

Comment: The first proofs of this result are by Lam and Leibler-Vitale. See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404977900305.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the following is a simple combinatorial argument which constructs the most dominant semistandard $\lambda$-tableau of content $\mu$ whenever $\lambda\trianglerighteq\mu$.  (n.b. I haven't followed the reference given in Richard Stanley's comment, so I don't know whether I'm duplicating what's done there.)

In a nutshell, the idea is "put the largest numbers as low as possible". So let $l$ be the length of $\mu$, and start the tableau by putting the $\mu_l$ $l$s in the bottom boxes of columns as far to the left as possible subject to the condition that if any box has an $l$ and there is a box directly to the right, then that box must also have an $l$ in it.  (Another way of saying this is: put $l$s at the bottom of the first $\mu_l$ columns, and then slide these $l$s to the ends of their rows.)  If we let $j$ be maximal such that $\lambda_j\geq\mu_l$, this means that we are putting $\lambda_x-\lambda_{x+1}$ $l$s at the end of row $x$ for each $x>j$, and $\mu_l-\lambda_{j+1}$ $l$s at the end of row $j$.

To fill in the rest of the tableau, we work recursively. Let $\hat\lambda$ denote the partition whose Young diagram comprises the boxes that are still empty, and let $\hat\mu$ be the partition $(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_{l-1})$. Then as long as $\hat\lambda\trianglerighteq\hat\mu$, we can fill in the rest of the tableau with a semistandard $\hat\lambda$-tableau of content $\hat\mu$, which gives us what we need.

So we need to show that $\hat\lambda_1+\dots+\hat\lambda_x\geq\hat\mu_1+\dots+\hat\mu_x$ for every $x$. For $x<j$ or $x\geq l$ this is immediate from the fact that $\lambda\trianglerighteq\mu$, so take $j\leq x<l$. Observe that $$\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_x=n-(\lambda_{x+1}+\dots+\lambda_l)\geqslant n-(l-x)\lambda_{x+1}$$while $$\mu_1+\dots+\mu_x=n-(\mu_{x+1}+\dots+\mu_l)\leqslant n-(l-x)\mu_l.$$ So $$(\hat\lambda_1+\dots+\hat\lambda_x)-(\hat\mu_1+\dots+\hat\mu_x)=(\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_{x+1}-\mu_l)-(\mu_1+\dots+\mu_x)\geqslant(l-x-1)(\mu_l-\lambda_{x+1})\geqslant0$$ as required.

Comment: Beautiful. I wonder whether relationship between $\lambda\unrhd\mu$ and $\hat\lambda\unrhd\hat\mu$ has any representation-theoretic meaning.

Comment: Dear Matt, I just came across your paper which shows, in type $A$, that if $\mu \geq \nu$ then $K_{\lambda \mu} \leq K_{\lambda \nu}$. Do you know if the corresponding statement is true in all types? See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275740/bounding-weight-multiplicities-by-number-of-coxeter-elements for context.

Comment: This answer was very useful to me! Just a trivial remark that the inequality
$$(\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_{x+1}-\mu_l)-(\mu_1+\dots+\mu_x)\geq 0$$
follows directly from $\mu_l\leq \mu_{x+1}$ (since $x<l$) and the definition of the dominance order.

Comment: For those seeking a reference, the statement that if $\mu \geq \nu$ then $K_{\lambda\mu} \leq K_{\lambda\nu}$ is Theorem 2 in [Dennis E. White, "Monotonicity and unimodality of the pattern inventory"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870880900596).

Answer (score 3):

The following argument is reproduced from the proof of Lemma 3.7.3 in the book *Representation Theory of the Symmetric Groups: The Okounkov–Vershik Approach, Character Formulas, and the Partition Algebras*, by Tullio Ceccherini-Silberstein, Fabio Scarabotti, and Filippo Tolli (Cambridge University Press, 2010).

The proof is by induction on $n$. Suppose that $\lambda$ has $k$ parts and $\mu$ has $h$ parts, and that $\lambda\ge \mu$. Say that the positive integer $i$ is *removable for the pair $(\lambda,\mu)$* if,
after setting
$$\tilde\lambda := (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_{i-1}, \lambda_i-1, \lambda_{i+1}, \ldots, \lambda_k)$$
and
$$\tilde\mu := (\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_{h-1}, \mu_h-1),$$
$\tilde\lambda$ is still a partition (i.e., $\lambda_i > \lambda_{i+1}$) and $\tilde\lambda \ge \tilde\mu$.  In particular, if the $i$th row of a SSYT of shape $\lambda$ and content $\mu$ contains the number $h$, then $i$ is removable for $(\lambda,\mu)$. Also, $k$ is always removable for the pair $(\lambda,\mu)$.

Let $i$ be the smallest removable integer for the pair $(\lambda,\mu)$, and let $\tilde\lambda$ and $\tilde\mu$ be as above. By the inductive hypothesis, we may construct a SSYT $\tilde T$ of shape $\tilde\lambda$ and content $\tilde\mu$. Moreover, by minimality of $i$, $\tilde T$ does not contain an entry $h$ in any row $j<i$. So if we add to $\tilde T$ a box at the end row $i$ with entry $h$, then we get a SSYT $T$ of shape $\lambda$ and content $\mu$.

Comment: Alex Yong has pointed out to me that this proof is wrong. The step "Moreover, by minimality of $i$, $\tilde T$ does not contain an entry $h$ in any row $j<i$" is incorrect. For a counterexample, take $\lambda=(5,5)$ and $\mu=(4,2,2,2)$. Then $\tilde\lambda = (5,4)$ and $\tilde\mu=(4,2,2,1)$, and there is an SSYT $\tilde T$ of shape $\tilde\lambda$ and content $\tilde\mu$ with a $4$ at the end of the first row, which cannot be extended to an SSYT of shape $\lambda$ and content $\mu$. I am not going to delete this post, however, as I think it's useful to record the fact that this proof is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The proof I know is more representation-theoretic than combinatorial; the condition $\lambda \unrhd \mu$ is replaced by the type-independent $\mu \in hull(W\cdot \lambda) \cap (\lambda +$ root lattice$)$. It goes as follows, inducting on the rank of the semisimple part of the group $G$. The rank $1$ case is standard $SL_2$ rep theory.

Pick a simple root $\alpha$, with $L_\alpha = T \cdot (SL_2)_\alpha$ the corresponding Levi subgroup, and consider the weights $\mu + \mathbb Z\alpha$. There will be a largest and a smallest $k$ such that $\lambda \unrhd \mu + k\alpha$; call them $k_\pm$. They satisfy the same condition as $\mu$, so we hope them to be weights of $V_\lambda$. Once we know they are, then we can use the $L_\alpha$ rep theory to say that $\mu$ is a weight, too.

So we've reduced to dealing with $\mu + k_\pm \alpha$. We need to argue that they are actually on the facets of $hull(W\cdot\lambda)$ (i.e. even had we considered $\mu+\mathbb R\alpha$ these would still be the right $k_\pm$) and I don't quite remember how that's done but would claim it's easy in the type $A$ case that motivates you. Then, we observe that the weight multiplicities on a facet are those of an irrep of a corank $1$ Levi subgroup (as is easily seen by Weyl invariance + the Kostant multiplicity formula), and use induction on rank.

In the SSYT situation this all goes as follows. Take $\alpha$ to be the first simple root. Then $k_+ = \lambda_1-\mu_1$, and $\mu + k_+ \alpha = (\lambda_1, \mu_2-k_+, \mu_3, \ldots)$. Any SSYT with that weight will have to have a first row of all $1$s. Filling in the rest of the SSYT is possible by induction. Now apply the $-\alpha$ crystal operator $k_+$ times to get an SSYT of weight $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a representation theoretic argument. I hope it is correct.

Consider the weight diagram of the irreducible representation $V_\lambda$ (of highest weight $\lambda$) of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$. The weight space associated to $\mu$ in this weight diagram has dimension $K_{\lambda\mu}$. So it is enough to show that each weight associated to $\mu$ appears in the weight diagram of $V_\lambda$ when $\lambda\geq\mu$. This should follow from the symmetry of the weight diagram.

For example, in $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ case, directly by inspection one can see that the weights that appear in the weight diagram of $V_\lambda$ correspond to the partitions of the form $\mu = (\lambda_1-k,\lambda_2+k)$ and these are the partitions such that $\mu\leq\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple constructive argument:

If $K_{\lambda \mu} \neq 0 $, then there is a semistandard tableau on $\lambda$ of type $\mu$. In a semistandard tableau, a box with $i$ can occur in atmost the $i^{th}$ row (as columns are strictly increasing).  There are $\mu_1 \,1's, \mu_2 \,2's,\ldots \mu_i \,i's, $ which can atmost occur upto the $i^{th}$ row of $\lambda$ which immediately gives us the inequality
$$\mu_1 +\mu_2 + \cdots +\mu_i \leq \lambda_1 +\lambda_2 +\cdots + \lambda_i.$$

For the converse, given the inequality, we just need to produce a semistandard tableau on $\lambda$ of type $\mu$. Let $\nu_i = \min (\lambda_i,\mu_i)$, and we fill $\nu_i \, i's$ in the $i^{th}$ row of $\lambda$. We exhaust all the $1's$ as $\mu_1\leq \lambda_1 (\implies \nu_1=\mu_1)$. Lets us say that we exhaust all the $(i-1)'s$, and the tableau is still semistandard. If $\mu_i = \nu_i$, then the $i's$ have also been exhausted, otherwise we have $\mu_i - \lambda_i$ many $i's$ left to be filled inside the boxes till the $i^{th}$ row, which we start to fill sequentially in the left over boxes in the first $i$ rows, going down a row only when one is completely filled ( this can be done as we have that $\mu_1 +\mu_2 + \cdots +\mu_i \leq \lambda_1 +\lambda_2 +\cdots + \lambda_i$). This need not give us a semistandard tableau, so we stop when we have $j$ such that $i$ occurs in the same column of the $(j-1)^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ rows. In the $j^{th}$ row, we find the first element on the left of the box with $i$ which is filled with the largest $k$ such that $k<i$, and for this $k$, we find the smallest $k'$ in the $(j-1)^{th}$ row such that $k \leq k'$, and we do a cyclic exchange of boxes, sending $k$ to the box of $k'$, and shifting everything in the $(j-1)^{th}$ row starting from $k'$ to its right, which leaves us with the box with $i$. We shift the boxes in the column that initially contained $k$ one up till atmost the $i^{th}$ row or a row containing a box with entry $>i$, and the last empty box in the column gets the leftover $i$. This shift keeps the table semistandard, and one can apply this shift repeatedly to bring a non semistandard tableau to a semistandard tableau.